# Group by MinMaxScaler in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I would like to apply minmax scaler to column X2 and X3 in dataframe df and add columns X2_Scale and X3_Scale for each month.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Month': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    'X1': [12,10,100,55,65,60,35,25,10,15,30,40,50],
    'X2': [10,15,24,32,8,6,10,23,24,56,45,10,56],
    'X3': [12,90,20,40,10,15,30,40,60,42,2,4,10]
})
```

Below code is what I tried but got en error.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

cols = df.columns[2:4]
df[cols + 'scale'] = df.groupby('Month')[cols].scaler.fit_transform(df[cols])
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Approach 1

Group and transform the columns `X2` and `X3` using a scaling function which applies the min-max scaling transformation and returns the scaled values

```
def scale(X):
    X_ = np.atleast_2d(X)
    return pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_), X.index)

df[cols + '_scale'] = df.groupby('Month')[cols].apply(scale)
```

#### Approach 2

Lets stick to the basics and calculate the `min`, `max` values from corresponding columns `X2` and `X3` for each group, then apply the scaling formula to the columns using the calculated min-max values

```
g = df.groupby('Month')[cols]
min_, max_ = g.transform('min'), g.transform('max')
df[cols + '_scale'] = (df[cols] - min_) / (max_ - min_)
```

#### Result

```
    Month   X1  X2  X3  X2_scale  X3_scale
0       1   12  10  12  0.153846  0.025000
1       1   10  15  90  0.346154  1.000000
2       1  100  24  20  0.692308  0.125000
3       1   55  32  40  1.000000  0.375000
4       1   65   8  10  0.076923  0.000000
5       1   60   6  15  0.000000  0.062500
6       2   35  10  30  0.000000  0.482759
7       2   25  23  40  0.282609  0.655172
8       2   10  24  60  0.304348  1.000000
9       2   15  56  42  1.000000  0.689655
10      2   30  45   2  0.760870  0.000000
11      2   40  10   4  0.000000  0.034483
12      2   50  56  10  1.000000  0.137931
```